# gcc not generating debug files

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

I want to compile an application with debug information using gcc and gdb. When I do the following, the debug (`.dSYM`) files are generated correctly:

```
gcc -ggdb src/test.c -o build/test
```

If I, however, split this into a compile step and a link step, like this:

```
gcc -ggdb -c src/test.c -o build/test.o
gcc -ggdb build/test.o -o dist/bin/test
```

… no `.dSYM` files are generated at all, and therefore `gdb` does not show me the source line of code where a crash occurs, which makes debugging a lot more difficult. Since I have quite a bit of source files, compiling and linking them all in a single `gcc` invocation is not possible.

How can I let gcc generate the `.dSYM` files when using separate compile and link steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also specify -g3 in you compilation options so that gcc puts debug symbols right into the binary, not in a separate file. Not sure if that is what you need.

Comment: Question, by adding the -g3 will put all the debug symbols in the bin? That would be the same as the debug symbols from the .dSYM?

Answer (score 3):

Check the second comment on the first answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584825/dsym-directories-while-compiling-c-code-in-macos).

Its a quirk. Maybe you can run the "dsymutil" program manually to generate dSYM files.