dSYM not generated when building with make
On macOS 12.7.5 (Monterey) using gcc to compile *.c: gcc version 13.2.0, with gnu make 3.81, (I prefer command line tools over XCode), when I pass CFLAGS = -g in a makefile I get full debugging symbols inside the executable but no .dSYM directory.  In other words, the symbols are not stripped.  However, when I type a typical gcc command:
    gcc -g filename1.c filename2.c -o filename

directly from the command line, the .dSYM directory is generated. I can debug either image with lldb as lldb knows how to read a .dSYM.  The unstripped executable has the symbols but the .dSYM is valuable in its own right.  I can obviously build for release without -g, but this means two separate make tasks.  How can I configure the makefile to cause the .dSYM to be generated?  That's the whole point of make, to avoid having to type a complex multi-file build command.  What am I missing re .dSYM?
Here is an example makefile.  All of mine follow this pattern.
# make description file to build a family of hashing programs

LANG   = -std=c11
GCOBJS = distanceGC.o hashtblGC.o ../GreatCircle/greatcircle.o
FOBJS  = ftlhash.o
HOBJS  = hashtbl.o argv.o

GCHDRS = hashGC.h ../GreatCircle/greatcircle.h
FHDRS  = ftlhash.h
HHDRS  = hashtbl.h ftlhash.h

CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

distanceGC : ${GCOBJS}
    ${CC} ${LANG} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${GCOBJS}

${GCOBJS} : ${GCHDRS}

../GreatCircle/greatcircle.o : ../GreatCircle/greatcircle.h
    cd /Users/wills/src/c/GreatCircle; make all

ftlhash : ${FOBJS}
    ${CC} ${LANG} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${FOBJS}

${FOBJS} : ${FHDRS}

hashtbl : ${HOBJS}
    ${CC} ${LANG} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${HOBJS}

${HOBJS} : ${HHDRS}

all : ftlhash hashtbl distanceGC

clean :
    /bin/rm -f core *.o
    cd /Users/wills/src/c/GreatCircle; /bin/rm -f core *.o
    /bin/rm /Users/wills/src/c/HASHTABLE/greatcircle.h
    /bin/ln -s /Users/wills/src/c/GreatCircle/    greatcircle.h /Users/wills/src/c/HASHTABLE/greatcircle.h

Here are sample build commands to recompile one of those targets:
touch ftlhash.c
make ftlhash

This yields:
gcc -g   -c -o ftlhash.o ftlhash.c
gcc -std=c11 -g -o ftlhash ftlhash.o

I'm guessing there is some Apple utility that an XCode build, or a command line invocation uses by defaut, to strip out the symbols and create the .dSYM, which my makefile is not doing.  My command line direct invocation of gcc produced:
drwxr-xr-x   3 wills  staff     96 Jul 15 15:03 ftlhash.dSYM

UPDATE: Looks like Apple's dsymutil in macOS is that tool. Now to teach make how to use it.
Thank you Jonathan Leffler for back and forth discussion of issue. /usr/bin/dsymutil $@ added to make build targets solves the problem.
For conditional execution you can do:
ifneq (,$(findstring -g, $(CFLAGS)))
    /usr/bin/dsymutil $@
endif

But be aware. Only the actual command is preceded with a tab. The ifneq and endif make statements are not commands, so must not have a leading tab.

Makefiles usually use separate recipes for compiling .c->.o and linking.o->executable. That may require different options to get what you want.

I sincerely doubt this is actually a problem with make.  You haven't shown us the actual commands that make invokes, and how they differ from the command you show here that you type at the shell prompt.  If you type the same commands make invokes at the shell prompt, not these different commands, do you get this ".dSYM directory"?

I will edit the original post to include the makefile.

Whoa!  That -c on the first gcc line generated by the make ftlhash command suppresses the generation of the .dSYM.  It is not clear to me why make added this option, since I did not specify it.  If I leave it out of the invocation of gcc at the shell prompt I get the .dSYM.  I can see what it is but not why.

You can't leave it out.  The -c option tells the compiler to generate an object file.  If you take it out, then the compiler will attempt to link a program and that will cause errors since obviously there are missing symbols.

Except...if I type   gcc -g ftlhash.c -o ftlhash   at the shell prompt I get the .dSYM.  I did not type a -c but gcc must have included it as a default, and other linker magic that is far from obvious.  make explicitly puts -c in the invocation and I don't get the .dSYM.   I want to trust make but I can't until I resolve this mystery.

None of what you wrote is true.  The compiler will never "magically" add options.  Probably reading a manual about GCC would be useful, to understand what these options mean.  The reason this worked is that you have exactly one source file in your program, ftlhash.c.  When you wrote gcc -g ftlhash.c -o ftlhash is created a program ftlhash, just like I said above.  It did not create an object file.
Since you only have one source file, that's fine.  If you want to create an object file, which GNU Make does, then you must use -c.

I used the single C source file as a simple example.  That make file can build three separate executables.  None have .dSYM with make.  All have .dSYM when I type out the laborious gcc command in the shell.  make is supposed to make our jobs easier.  Be a little careful how arrogant you get with your critique.  It is unwelcome without a solution, which is why I posted the question, to get an answer from someone who knows more than I do.  I can read docos but I can find nothing on point about ,dSYM, until dsymutil.  Do you know how dsymutil is used???

I know quite a lot about make, and compilers in general.  I know very little about MacOS/iOS software; I don't give Apple any money due to their business practices.  So I don't know much about dSYM, but I know that whether or not it's created is not related to make itself.  It may very well be related to how the linker is invoked.  But if, as I mentioned in my first comment, you cut and paste the exact same commands that make invokes to your shell prompt I'm confident you will find that you do not get dSYM output created.  So it's not a make issue per se.

Some googling leads me to the second comment in the first answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584825/dsym-directories-while-compiling-c-code-in-macos So it looks like this is a known quirk of MacOS since at least 2009.

I've seen this behaviour.
There's an option to Clang (aka gcc on a Mac):

-dsym-dir <dir> — Directory to output dSYM's (if any) to

You might be able to use that in your linking command line, but see below.
I've not previously investigated when the .dSYM directory is not created.  Using -g on the linking command line is one key factor.  Without that, the .dSYM directory is not created.  But there is more to it than that.  If I link object files (and libraries) only, the .dSYM directory is not created, even with the -g flag.  If I specify at least one source file on the linking command line (and -g), then I seem to get the .dSYM file.
Many makefiles compile the various source files to object files and then link those object files.  So, those programs probably do not get a .dSYM directory created.
Here's a simple shell script to demo the behaviour:
#!/bin/sh

source=cmplx67

clean()
{
    rm -fr $source $source.o $source.dSYM
}

set -x
clean
ls -l
clang -o $source $source.c
ls -l
clean
clang -g -o $source $source.c
ls -l
clean
clang -g -c $source.c
clang -g -o $source $source.o
ls -l
clean
clang -g -c $source.c
clang -g -o $source $source.o -dsym-dir $source.dSYM
ls -l
clean

The file cmplx67.c is a trivial program.
When run, I get output such as:
2024-07-15 16:49:22
+ clean
+ rm -fr cmplx67 cmplx67.o cmplx67.dSYM
+ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff  478 Jul 15 16:20 cmplx67.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff  333 Jul 15 16:47 demo.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff  194 Jul 15 16:23 makefile
+ clang -o cmplx67 cmplx67.c
+ ls -l
total 96
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jonathanleffler  staff  33496 Jul 15 16:49 cmplx67
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    478 Jul 15 16:20 cmplx67.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    333 Jul 15 16:47 demo.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    194 Jul 15 16:23 makefile
+ clean
+ rm -fr cmplx67 cmplx67.o cmplx67.dSYM
+ clang -g -o cmplx67 cmplx67.c
+ ls -l
total 96
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jonathanleffler  staff  33832 Jul 15 16:49 cmplx67
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    478 Jul 15 16:20 cmplx67.c
drwxr-xr-x  3 jonathanleffler  staff     96 Jul 15 16:49 cmplx67.dSYM
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    333 Jul 15 16:47 demo.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    194 Jul 15 16:23 makefile
+ clean
+ rm -fr cmplx67 cmplx67.o cmplx67.dSYM
+ clang -g -c cmplx67.c
+ clang -g -o cmplx67 cmplx67.o
+ ls -l
total 104
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jonathanleffler  staff  33800 Jul 15 16:49 cmplx67
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    478 Jul 15 16:20 cmplx67.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff   2968 Jul 15 16:49 cmplx67.o
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    333 Jul 15 16:47 demo.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    194 Jul 15 16:23 makefile
+ clean
+ rm -fr cmplx67 cmplx67.o cmplx67.dSYM
+ clang -g -c cmplx67.c
+ clang -g -o cmplx67 cmplx67.o -dsym-dir cmplx67.dSYM
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dsym-dir cmplx67.dSYM' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
+ ls -l
total 104
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jonathanleffler  staff  33800 Jul 15 16:49 cmplx67
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    478 Jul 15 16:20 cmplx67.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff   2968 Jul 15 16:49 cmplx67.o
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    333 Jul 15 16:47 demo.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff    194 Jul 15 16:23 makefile
+ clean
+ rm -fr cmplx67 cmplx67.o cmplx67.dSYM

As you can see, the -dsym-dir option was ignored when the object file was linked.  When I compiled and linked the source file with the option, it was used.  (I experimented with -dsym-dir=cmplx67.dSYM and got a directory =cmplx67.dSYM!)
You can adapt this to make more experiments.  What .dSYM directory is created if there a multiple source files on the command line, for example.
Testing on an M2 MacBook Pro running macOS Sonoma 14.5 and using:
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0

I've seen this behaviour on many prior versions of macOS, including those predating macOS Monterey 12.7.5.  I've used MacOS X and macOS fairly solidly since at least Mac OS X Jaguar 10.2, and I think I used Mac OS X 10.0 Cheetah, but I'd be hard-pressed to prove that now.
Using the name gcc instead of clang doesn't change the behaviour.

I tried ftlhash : ${FOBJS}
${CC} ${LANG} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${FOBJS} -dsym-dir ./$@.dSYM
in my make file and also got the "argument unused" warning.  Frustrating :-(

I just discovered /usr/bin/dsymutil on my mac.  Invoking dsymutil ftlhash produced an ftlhash.dSYM directory fully populated with DWARF.  dsymutil has -h help and a man page.  If this is the actual tool clang uses to generate a .dSYM, the trick will be to get make to use it.

Rewrite the rule(s) for compiling code so you run dsymutil after linking the executable.

Success.  Added /usr/bin/dsymutil $@ to each target build command in make and /bin/rm -fr *.dSYM to clean task.  Interesting Jonathan, that you answered a somewhat similar question in '09 re macOS 10.6.2 and dsymutil.  My take is all of this is based on Apple's commitment to LLVM, and there are now some non-fatal anomalies in make's internals that are undocumented.  make processes build commands and -g and -c are internally inconsistent, and have been so for a long time.  I discovered dsymutil reading LLVM documentation, not Apple or GNU make docs, since LLVM's role is code generation.

Thanks, and well done.  I had forgotten about answering a question in 2009 about dsymutil — but it was quite a while ago now.  I didn't find it on SO; was it on one of the other sites?  It doesn't matter very much.

Yes on SO: dSYM Directories While Compiling C++ Code in MacOS.  Actually, I want conditional .dSYM so I did: ifneq (,$(findstring -g, $(CFLAGS)))  /usr/bin/dsymutil $@ endif  Great working with you.

Ah — it was in a comment to a C++ question.  Two hits against my searching.  But yes, I seem to have known back then what I rediscovered yesterday and documented in this answer.  It's nice that my findings now are consistent with what I said back then.  It hadn't been an issue for me — I don't often use lldb — but it was worth finding out what gives.  Thanks for prompting me to investigate and report.
